# How to change locale by GWT without javascript

Tags: java, gwt, locale

Currently I change my locale in GWT using a javascript as a native code. if the user click on changeLocale button on my GUI, i call this native method.

Is there any java method/way to do that without using any native code???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you looked at the [`Showcase` sample](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/showcase/src/com/google/gwt/sample/showcase/client/ShowcaseShell.java#322)?

Redux'd, it's as easy as:

```
Window.Location.assign( // or replace()
   Window.Location.createUrlBuilder()
      .setParameter(LocaleInfo.getLocaleQueryParam(), "fr-FR")
      .buildString());
```

Comment: It looks like replace and assign have the same effect. What is the difference?

Comment: After an `assign`, you can hit the "previous page" button in your browser and go back to where you were before the `assign` (because `assign` will append a new entry in the browser's history). `replace` replaces the current entry in the browser's history with a new one, so the previous page is the same as before, and you cannot go back to the previously selected locale using your browser's history.